# Emberjs Person is not defined

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to emberjs and trying to follow the guide from their site about Classes and Instances 
So I try to run the following code:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();


App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  say: function(thing) {
    alert(thing);
  }
});


var person = Person.create();
person.say("Hello") // alerts " says: Hello"
```

but i get ReferenceError: Person is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({ ... });` so to create a new instance you need to use `var person = App.Person.create();`. You forgot the `App` namespace in your sample.

Comment: copy pasted from emberjs guide

Comment: @tHIScOdeIsBeNaNaS I created a PR [here](https://github.com/emberjs/website/pull/1264). I hope it helps.